# Removing duplicate rows in panel data by criteria

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a basic question,and i hope is not a replication. I had a look around but I was not able to find someone that directly addressed the question.
I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
   df <- data.frame("Reporter" = c("USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", 
"EU","EU", "EU","EU" ), 
                 "Year" = c(1970, 1970, 1980, 1990, 1970, 1980, 
 1980,1990), 
                 "Val" = c(1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1),
                "Val2" = c(0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1))
```

the issue is that I have some duplicated country year observation, and this create problems for my analysis. (val1 for US 1970, and val2 for EU 1980).

I would like to delete duplicated rows keeping always the highest value of non-matching scores (1). Since I have this issue for hundreds of rows, I was wondering whether there is an automatic approach to find out which data is duplicated and delete the one with the smaller value

I have found a way to individuate duplicated rows

```
df1<- df%>% select(Reporter, Year)
df1$duplicat <- duplicated(df1) %>% filter(duplicat=="TRUE")
```

but I am still not sure how to delete them according to the specified criteria. normally I would use anti_join, but it does not work as df1 data matches two rows.

I thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use data.table:

```
setDT(df)[order(-Val)][,.SD[1,], by = .(Reporter, Year)]
```

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to order the `df` by `Val` and `Val2`, then remove duplicates where both `Reporter` and `Year` columns match:

```
df <- df[order(df[,'Val'],df[,'Val2'], decreasing=TRUE),]
df <- df[!duplicated(df[c("Reporter","Year")]),]


  Reporter Year Val Val2
4      USA 1990   1    1
8       EU 1990   1    1
1      USA 1970   1    0
3      USA 1980   1    0
6       EU 1980   0    1
5       EU 1970   0    0
```

Answer (score 2):

A `dplyr` option would be to `arrange` the dataframe by `Val` and `Val2` and select the last row for each `Reporter` and `Year`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(Val, Val2) %>%
  group_by(Reporter, Year) %>%
  slice(n())

#  Reporter  Year   Val  Val2
#  <fct>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 EU        1970     0     0
#2 EU        1980     0     1
#3 EU        1990     1     1
#4 USA       1970     1     0
#5 USA       1980     1     0
#6 USA       1990     1     1
```

Comment: thank you for this, I usually prefer using dplyr, however it told me that slice was not applicable to an object of class data table... nevertheless i was able to solve the problem with data.table! thanx anyways

Comment: @Alessandro I was not aware you had `data.table` since the data you shared was dataframe. Nonetheless, when I change `df` to `data.table` it still works for me. Can you try restarting your session and check again?

Comment: uhm that is curious: this is the error that r tells me: `Error in UseMethod("slice") : 
  no applicable method for 'slice' applied to an object of class "c('grouped_df', 'tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')"`, any idea of wat it could be?

Comment: I see. I think there might be some package conflict. Can you explicitly mention the package name and try `df %>%
  dplyr::arrange(Val, Val2) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Reporter, Year) %>%
  dplyr::slice(n())` ?

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table::setorder()` I gave your problem a shot. You could use a pipe and put this into one line. Gives the same result as heds1 but if you have a large data set it would be worth it to compare the two with a benchmark.

**Code:**

```r
dt1 <- data.table("Reporter" = c("USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", 
                                "EU","EU", "EU","EU" ), 
                 "Year" = c(1970, 1970, 1980, 1990, 1970, 1980, 
                            1980,1990), 
                 "Val1" = c(1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1),
                 "Val2" = c(0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1))

dt2 <- setorder(dt1, -`Val1`, -`Val2`)
dt3 <- unique(dt2, by = c("Reporter", "Year"))
```

**Output:**

```r
   Reporter Year Val1 Val2
1:      USA 1990    1    1
2:       EU 1990    1    1
3:      USA 1970    1    0
4:      USA 1980    1    0
5:       EU 1980    0    1
6:       EU 1970    0    0
```